# Facebook update payments status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, payment, facebook-payments

I have add payments system for our application. On test regulars and asynchronous payments, with test payments and it work's good.
But I have difficaults with read asynchronous payments.
All asynchronous payments have status "initiated" and never changed.
I think I need manualy change status with graph api:

```
POST /PAYMENT_ID?status=settled&amount=1.00&currency=USD
```

but have error

```
"message": "(#101) payment provider does not match payment method."
```

I think it is wrong way

Also I think that facebook send verify requests to "payment callback URL" from application payments settings, but silence =\

And also, I cant'n close facebook payments dialog width "ok" button for mobile payments I have only "cancel" button after verify transaction with SMS-code.

Comment: Please read the docs.

"An initiated payment designates the payment was only initiated and has not yet fully completed. You will commonly see this initiated state for certain payment methods which require long time to settle"

"Facebook will not send Realtime Updates for payments in an initiated state."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/realtimeupdates/

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have read documentation, but 3 day is to logn, I prepare to panic.This morning I see that some payments change status. Slow payment provider is our country.

But still have problem with payments dialog and "OK" button.